# In Android, is it poor design to navigate to an Activity using nav_graph in contrast to using intents?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to navigate back to the login activity after a sign out or deleting a user. Is there a better approach between using intents or using the nav_graph. The pros of the nav_graph is more easily managed navigation code, but how about using intents?

```
<action
            android:id="@+id/action_editProfile_to_loginActivity"
            app:destination="@id/loginActivity"
            app:launchSingleTop="false"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
```

Opposed to something alike:

```
val intentCreateProfile = Intent(this@ActivityPhoneAuthentification, ActivityCreateProfile::class.java)
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        startActivity(intentCreateProfile)
        finish()
```

Comment: It is only very recently that the nav graph even supports navigating to activities. So it is too early for a convention or general best practice to have emerged.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know - it seems ok, as long as you can send/access all the things in navgraph comparing to intents...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).